# Why image uploaded with spatie-laravel-media-library-plugin not found under storage?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, laravel-storage

On laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 site I have added spatie-laravel-media-library-plugin and upoading file with comnponent :

```
SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload::make('image')
    ->disk('local')
    ->preserveFilenames(),
```

I see row in media table and file is uploaded under /ProjectRoot/storage/app/app_media/5/ subdirectory, but in browser I see
that 404 error is returned on

```
http://local-host.com/storage/app_media/5/wizdom.jpg
```

url

I found valid file under

```
file:///ProjectRoot/storage/app/app_media/5/wizdom.jpg
```

path

but

```
/ProjectRoot/public/storage/
```

subdirectory is empty.

I run several times commands

```
cd public
rm storage
cd ../
php artisan storage:link

INFO  The [public/storage] link has been connected to [storage/app/public].
```

With output above that link was created with success.

How that can be fixed ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.35.0",
"filament/filament": "^3.0-stable",
"filament/spatie-laravel-media-library-plugin": "^3.1",
"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.15.0",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It could be a port number . Example in your .env file (localhost) if you running it on your local environment   your url app should include the port number  APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: In my .env APP_URL=http://local-host.com
just as in my url I try to open url in browser.
http://local-host.com that is apache2 hosting under kubuntu 22.04
Have I to apply port also ?